# how to count files only in specific subdirectories located deeply in the hierarchy?

Tags: bash, count, find

I need to count all sessions files `sess_*` located in TMP directories (Debian machine) and **know path to each TMP with the count for each one**.

All parent direcotries are in `/somepath/to/clientsDirs`.

The directory structure for one client is

```
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/someDirZx
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/someDirZy
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/tmp
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/someDirZz
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/...
../ClientDirX/webDirYX/someDirZN

../ClientDirX/webDirYY/someDirZx
../ClientDirX/webDirYY/someDirZy
../ClientDirX/webDirYY/tmp
../ClientDirX/webDirYY/someDirZz
../ClientDirX/webDirYY/...
../ClientDirX/webDirYY/someDirZN
```

all `someDirZ` and `tmp` directories have a various count of subdirectories. **Sessions files are in tmp dir only and not in tmp subdirectories**. In one `tmp` dir could be more than millions `sess_*` files, so the solution needs to be very time effective.

X, YY, etc. in directory names are always numbers, but not in a continuous line, e.g.:

```
ClientDir1/webDir3/*
ClientDir4/webDir31/*
ClientDir4/webDir35/* 
ClientDir18/webDir2/*
```

Could you please help me **count all `sess_*` files in each `tmp` dir** by command line or bash script?

Comment: *solution need to be very time effective.* Okay, but what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not good at Linux commands, so I had two problems that I couldn't solve -> how to add a counting condition for TMP dir only and how to create a loop to go through the directory tree. I couldn't figure it out based on the many posts I read here on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: change of answer after changing the sense of a question

The whole task is divided into 3 parts.
I changed the directory names to simpler.

1.Build a list of tmp directories to search (first script)

```
#!/bin/bash
find /var/log/clients/sd*/wd*/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  -name "tmp" >list
```

explanation

```
-type d only search for directories
-maxdpth 1 specifies the maximum search depth
-name specifies the name of the items sought
>list redirects the result to the list file
* it is so-called shell globbing in this case means 
  any string of characters
```

We perform this task for two reasons in a separate file. First of all, the execution time will be significant. Secondly, the list of customers does not change very often and it makes no sense to check it every time.

2.iterating loop over list items in bash (see finaly script)

3.search for sess_* files in the tmp directory without including subdirectories

```
find /path/to/tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "sess_*" -exec printf "1" \; |wc -c
```

explanation

```
-type f only searches files
-exec executes any system command in this case, printf
 \; necessary part ending the -exec command, must contain a space!
```

-exec printf is used because not every version of find has a printf command built in, so this will also work on busyboxes or outside of the GNU world
If your find has printf, use it instead of -exec (-printf "1")

For more, see command `man find`

Finally the second script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in `cat list`
do
  printf "%s \t" $x
  find $x -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "sess_*" -exec printf "1" \; | wc -c
done
```

Example result:

```
/var/log/clients/sd1/wd1/tmp    3
/var/log/clients/sd2/wd1/tmp    62
```

EDIT: 
*Note in some versions find GNU (eg 4.7.0-git) when the order -maxdepth 1 changes the -type f program throws worning or does not work. It seems that these versions do not use the getopt mechanism for some reason. Other versions of find do not seem to have this problem.*

Comment: I tried your solution ... but I realized that I was misunderstood because I did not explicitly state that I do not need to know all the sess_ files in the whole directory tree, but I need to know all the sess_ files for each TMP directory separately (including identifying that TMP address book). I apologize for my mistake in the specification, I have already added this information.

Comment: when I put your first command `find /somepath/to/clientsDirs* -type f -name "sess_*"  |wc -l` to the command line --> I have got number for one TMP dir, that's fine. .... But when I put this same command (only with modification -exec instead |) to the bin/bash script, I have got error message `/somepath/to/clientsDirs: Is a directory` ... what I need modify to get number instead error?

Comment: @Radek The description is a bit vague. You want to count the number of sess_* files separately for each tmp directory. SomeDirXY catalogs etc. don't interest you at all? Did I get it right? As for embedding in the bash script, it is difficult to refer to it without seeing what exactly you did.

Comment: @Radek the order of the -type and -maxdepth options does not matter

Comment: Radek Thanks are nice but for SO it was accepted to approve the correct solutions.

Comment: 1.) change of parametrs order I do after I get error from my system about using maxdepth.
2.) I am new here like active user ... now I hope I have done all for accept your solution like the right one.

Comment: 2. Yes thanks. 1. What is this system and what version of find? Consider this in response. Usually programs use getopt or similar options to read and then the order is irrelevant.

Comment: @Radek I checked on several systems and versions (busybox, GNU, FreeBSD) everywhere regardless of order. Haven't you forgotten about the number 1? the argument is -maxdepth 1

Comment: root@machine:/# find /var/www/aaa/tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "sess_*" -exec printf "1" \; | wc -c   --->  result: 4788  ... but ...   root@machine:/# find /var/www/aaa/tmp -type f maxdepth 1  -name "sess_*" -exec printf "1" \; | wc -c    --->   find: paths must precede expression: maxdepth
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression] ----> result: 0 ... on Debian 8 Jessie

Comment: I corrected and added info at the bottom of the answer. Thanks for paying attention. I found find GNU 4.0.7-git which throws a warning but counts correctly. Perhaps other versions are more rotten.